# Issue with Blueimp fileupload button text

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, blueimp

I am using Blueimp File Upload and having some issues with the text of the button. When I press "Tab" key to reach to the FileUpload control, the button text gets disappeard. I have Googled it but not able to find an answer.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. Just added height:100% in the ".fileinput-button input" class.

Thanks